# Android: Loading multiple images

Tags: android, resources, bitmap

I have recently started developing a game in android, never used it before and was wondering if there is a simple way of getting a set of images loaded into the application. As my current implementation involves basically

Creating an int[] array,
Storing the values of each drawable into this array, **(now this has to be hand coded, so if I add any more images it has to be added programmitically)**

Then itterating through each item in the array and calling BitmapFactory to get the resource.
(Unfortunately I don't have the code with me as it is at home and I am at work, but that is the jist)

So 2 questions, is there a way of getting the drawables without having to put in each item manually to the int[] - ie looking for perhaps a file name prefix and then only loading the resource with the prefix?

Which leads me to my second question because I more than just these images in my drawable resource directory, is there a way to add extra organisation (folders) to manage the files better. As currently I have loads of images within the drawable file and how would I reference these sub folders/images.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have sub folders within the resources structure.  Android depends on the folder layout to determine which resource to use in what condition (localization, different screen resolutions, etc).

I'm not sure why exactly you are trying to load up a whole bunch of images, but there are a couple of (slower) methods that allow you to look up a resource by string name.  If you used a naming convention for your images you could look them up that way via [Resources.getIdentifier()][1].  However, in a game performance likely matters, so you are probably better off with a more manual approach using the int IDs directly since it is much more efficient.

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: See above comment, I couldnt type it all in here

Answer (score 0):

I am uploading a load of images as they will be shown to user for different items. Its not a system where responsiveness is critical so its okay in terms of what I want. Though...

> public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
>   Since: API Level 1
>
> Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry". The first two components (package and type) are optional if defType and defPackage, respectively, are specified here.
>
> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

They suggest using the resource id but if I want to add a file later on then I have to re-compile the app to include the extra file, this is where it bugs me, as the pic gets associated to an item that I have in a string array.  So I can add items to the array but not the images without a change of the code.

Surely there is a function to fix this?

Comment: You should edit your original question to add details, not post an answer.  Regardless, I don't understand your concern.  If you are using image resources, then you need to recompile the app to add a new image regardless of how you access the image.  If you don't want to have to recompile to change the images, then you can't use Android Resources and need to come up with your own solution.

Comment: Hey Mayra, yeh wasn't too sure where I was meant to put my reply, thanks for the advice. Also I was refering to how Android claims you can edit resources outside of a applications source code, yet if I want to add an item to my game (which requires an image, amongst other primative data types) I can't simply add the drawable resource and it will be picked up. Unlike the name which I store in a string array amongst the values resources. Which can be added because the array is looped through to add the new name.

Comment: Either thing, adding a new Image Resource, or changing an Array resource, would force you to recompile.  I don't see why that is a problem though, its not like you are going to be editing the Resources on the fly once your game is deployed.  If you really do want to do that, then don't use Resources.

Comment: Hey Mayra, I was under the impression that externalising resources in xml files was good because it allowed you to make changes to a system without the need for re-compilation i.e changing string values/arrays used. Now I know the practicality of this is pretty limited since I wont be able to go around to each app and use this. But during development if I wanted to include extra info (in say the array) I could just add them on the fly.